# Binding Primitives in Laravel Scope class

Tags: laravel

I have a global scope that is used for a few models. Here is the scope class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Scopes;

use App\Models\UserMeta;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Scope;

class WorkplaceScope implements Scope
{
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        $user_active_workplace = UserMeta::where(['user_id' => Auth::id(), 'meta_key' => 'active_workplace'])->first();
        $builder->where('workplace_id', $user_active_workplace->meta_value);
    }
}
```

I am assigning the scope by overriding the model's `boot` method:

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    static::addGlobalScope(new WorkplaceScope);
}
```

The problem is that I make a query inside the scope and that query is executed a lot of times for no reason. I was thinking of using primitive binding inside a service provider, but I can't figure out how to do it properly. I tried adding this inside the `AppServiceProvider`:

```
$this->app->when('App\Scopes\WorkplaceScope')
    ->needs('$user_active_workplace_meta_value')
    ->give(1);
```

but I don't know how to hint the service provider that the WorkplaceScope expects a $user_active_workplace_meta_value variable. Any idea how can I do this?

Comment: you hint the type of `user_active_workplace_meta_value` Where do you declare the var?

Comment: I added user_active_workplace_meta_value variable as a public property for the WorkplaceScope class.

Comment: If it is a string you might want to try `\string`